# Match nodes connected to same intermediary - cypher/neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I'm working on a graph with content nodes that are tagged with term nodes. I'm trying to get a query working that returns (matched) term nodes that are connected to the same content nodes as other (search) term nodes.

```
(matched:term)--(contentNode:content)--(search:term)
```

The problem I'm having is returning matched term nodes that are connected to content that has *all* of search terms connected to it, rather than any.

Here is a simplified version of my current query:

```
query = [
            'MATCH (matched:term)<-[:TAGGED_WITH]-(contentNode:content)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(searchTerms:term) ',
            'WHERE searchTerms.UUID IN {searchTerms} ',
            'RETURN DISTINCT matched.name AS name, matched.UUID AS UUID, matched.contentConnections AS connections ',
            'ORDER BY connections DESC LIMIT 10'
        ].join('\n');
```

Here is an example in practice - the top group of terms are the terms matched by my query, the bottom are the terms being used for the search:

[image: search image]

The term 'astronomy' should not be returned, but it is because some content tagged with 'image' is also tagged with 'astronomy'.

Graph representation of the results:

[image: graph rep 1]

Note that only one piece of content (the gray nodes) matches both terms (it's hard to tell because the node ID is what is displayed). What is expected is to only return the terms that are connected to the content that has been tagged with both "image" and "organ"

Another example:

[image: second search image]

This search should yield no terms, because no content is tagged with both 'organ' and 'astronomy', however, it is returning terms tagged to either.

Graph representation:

[image: graph rep 2]

I hope I've made my question clear. I've tried working with `count()` to group the results but struggling to get it to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Query:

```
query = [
    'MATCH (contentNode:content)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(searchTerms:term) ',
    'WITH contentNode, COUNT(contentNode) as countContent, searchTerms ',
    'WHERE searchTerms.UUID IN {searchTerms} AND countContent = {searchTermsCount} ',
    'MATCH (typeNode:termType)<-[:IS_TYPE]-(matched:term)<-[:TAGGED_WITH]-contentNode, ',
        'matched-[:HAS_LANGUAGE {languageCode: {language} }]-(termMeta:termMeta) ',
    'WHERE NOT matched.UUID IN {ignoreTerms}',
    'RETURN DISTINCT termMeta.name AS name, matched.UUID AS UUID, matched.contentConnections AS connections ',
    'ORDER BY connections DESC LIMIT 10'
].join('\n');
```

With the following two terms selected, the query is expected to return terms tagged to any of those pieces of content ('evolution', 'ant', etc.), however, with the above query, no terms are returned.

[image: update issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try splitting your query in two:

```
MATCH (contentNode:content)-[:TAGGED_WITH]->(searchTerms:term)
WHERE searchTerms.UUID IN {searchTerms}
WITH contentNode, COUNT(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt = {_searchTerms_size_} 
MATCH (matched:term)<-[:TAGGED_WITH]-contentNode    
RETURN DISTINCT matched.name AS name, matched.UUID AS UUID, matched.contentConnections AS connections
ORDER BY connections DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help RaduK, however this query does not quite work as expected. I could be that I broke it when adding back in the full complexity. Your answer also produces an error in that searhTerms must be included in the with clause to be able to filter based on the included terms. I've added another image to my question to illustrate the issue.

Comment: I've modified your answer to the correctly working query- The WHERE clause for the search terms needed to appear before the WITH clause, also it is desirable to return distinct nodes. Thanks again for your help- this is the second pickle you've helped me get out of.